# Big O analysis of a C exponentiation function

Tags: number-theory, analysis, asymptotics

I am trying to find the Big O of the following program.
int pow(long x , long n) {
if(n==1){
return x;
}
if(isEven(n)){
return pow(x, n/2) * pow(x, n/2)
} else{
return pow(x*x, n/2) * x;
}
}
.Let $T(1) = 1$.Each call to pow() results in two child subcalls resulting in
$T(N) = T(N/2) + T(N/2)  = 2^{N+1} - 1$  which in turn results in  $O(2^{N+1})$ worst case running time. Is it a correct analysis ?.